# Not sure how to convert the data in an xlsx file into monthly by year data without rewriting the whole dataset

Tags: excel, time-series

Here is the dataset
Table B.21  Arizona Average Retail Price of Residential Electricity (Cents per kWh)
Source:  http://www.eia.gov/electricity/data.cfm#sales

```
Year    Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2001    6.99    7.13    7.4     8.09    9.41    9.04    8.84    8.84    8.81    8.95    7.17    7.26
2002    7.01    7.17    7.46    7.69    9.37    8.97    8.65    8.78    8.79    8.99    7.37    7.46
2003    7.06    7.57    7.59    7.82    9.52    9.09    8.78    8.74    8.7     8.83    7.21    7.55
2004    7.27    7.49    7.61    8.05    9.26    9.1     8.88    8.87    8.96    8.79    8.05    7.86
2005    7.75    7.99    8.19    8.67    9.6     9.41    9.3     9.28    9.3     9.23    8.12    7.88
2006    8.05    8.21    8.38    8.92    10.19   10.05   9.9     9.88    9.89    9.88    8.74    8.56
2007    8.33    8.46    8.8     9.19    10.2    9.96    10.37   10.33   10.17   10.16   9.08    8.89
2008    8.85    9.02    9.38    10.02   11.03   11.06   10.95   10.86   10.63   10.46   9.55    9.61
2009    9.51    9.82    9.93    10.65   11.33   11.27   11.3    11.29   11.17   10.97   9.86    9.7
2010    9.57    9.84    9.98    10.24   11.75   11.74   11.78   11.59   11.52   10.96   10.14   10
2011    9.84    9.93    10.25   10.97   11.77   11.77   11.85   11.67   11.53   11.08   10.31   9.98
2012    10.01   10.26   10.44   11.17   11.88   11.9    11.86   11.83   11.66   11.36   10.73   10.41
2013    10.25   10.7    10.87   11.74   12.17   12.18   12.51   12.33   12.22   12.02   11.06   11.01
2014    10.92   11.23   11.32   11.97   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

and it is xlsx format.  Is there a way to re-format it to where it is two columns, one of which is the month-year, and the second is the observation?  The conversion of the dataset is not a problem that is for any class, but I need to use it for time series analysis, and am trying to put it in a format to be able to accomplish that.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Adam

Comment: @harun24hr thank you for the reformatting of the dataset to show how it actually appears in the xlsx file

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy exercise of just a few clicks with Power Query. Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as Get and Transform.

Load the dataset into Powerquery (either from a file or from a table in your Excel workbook), select the year column and execute the command "unpivot other columns".

[image]

That will sort the data into three columns, i.e. year, "attribute" and value. Rename the attribute  column to "month".

Next use the command to insert a new column by example, then type out "1-Jan-2001" and "1-Feb-2001" as the first two examples.

[image]

Power Query will then fill the column with the correct values. Parse the values as dates, so they are real dates. remove the columns you no longer need and save the query. You can format the date column to show just year and month.

If you can't or don't want to use Power Pivot, you can use a reverse pivot like this:

- select the data
- open the pivot wizard with Alt-D-P
- click "multiple consolidation ranges" > Next
- click "I will create the page fields" > Next
- select the data in the sheet and click Add, then > Next
- Click Finish
- in the new pivot table, drag the fields out of the rows and columns area to remove them. That leaves you with a single value.
- double click the number
- the flat table of all values will be in a new sheet
- rename the columns as desired
- to create a single column for the date, use this formula

=DATEVALUE("1-"&[@month]&"-"&[@year])

Adjust the formula to a text that is recognised in your region as a date and copy down. Copy the column with formulas and paste as values. Format the date to show only year and month. Delete the columns you don't need.

The beauty of the Power Query approach is that it can be repeated with a fresh data set with just one click, whereas the Pivot table approach requires you to go through all the steps each time.

Edit: I added steps to create real dates in one column. Note that the extra steps to create real dates as opposed to just text like "2001-Jan" are worth the work. The benefit is that real dates play much nicer in data sorting, pivots and chart axes. Enjoy.

Comment: Well, the format I am trying to achieve is a month/year and then the observation value for that, for example: Jan 2001 and 6.99.  So what I am trying to do is make it into two columns so I can do some time series analysis on the dataset, if that makes sense.

Comment: I thought the main challenge was the unpivoting, but if you really need to have it spelled out, I can write up how to create a formula for the combined year and date.

Comment: without having to actually go through and rewrite it by hand as a new file

Comment: I will freely admit I am Excel stupid and have not done much of any transformation of data files with Excel, so I am sorry if I seem like I just rolled out of fifth grade :)

Comment: I added steps for the all-in-one-column date.

Comment: so I loaded it into Powerquery, and when I select the year column, I don't see anywhere that the unpivot command can be accessed

Comment: Transform ribbon, Unpivot dropdown.

Comment: I added a few screenshots for the Power Query part.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help - it worked, but the conversion to R is doing something funky, and when I try to plot it it tries to plot as a bargraph, instead of using it as a time series, when I convert it to a time series.

Comment: You never mention any conversion to R in your question. I think that is a separate issue, unrelated to Excel.

Comment: I'm not sure it is separate.  I loaded the original set into R using xlsx, and tried to plot it as a time series, and R tried to use a barplot.  I then converted it to a csv file to see if that changed anything and it did not.  Next I used the converted file (as you gave great instructions for achieving above) and tried to convert it into a time series in R, and what it gave me was the original excel type setup, with year and months all separate, but instead of the values it threw in values of the months (1-168).  I'll include the code in the next comment

Comment: electricity.data <- read.xlsx("EP.xlsx", 2)
  electricity.data
  y.ts <- ts(electricity.data[,2], start=c(2001,1), freq=12)
  y.ts

Comment: this is a portion of the way R converted it to a time series:                   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2001  63  66  72  86 125 114 103 103 101 109  67  69
2002  64  67  73  79 123 111  94  98  99 112  71  73
2003  65  76  77  81 127 116  98  97  96 102  68  75

Comment: and I obviously am not very handy at posting code and all in this forum yet

Comment: Please calm down. Don't bombard this thread with comments. The steps in my answer, if followed correctly, will create real dates in Excel. I have pointed out that you need to ensure that the DateValue() function is fed a text string that is a date in **your region**. So you may need to adjust that formula to get a real date.  Maybe you need to have the month at the start instead of the day. You have shared precious little information about your region or other settings. So stop panicking and don't even start exporting to R before you know that it's a real date in Excel.

Comment: @ teylyn  Sorry, I wasn't trying to bombard the thread.  The actual issue was with the last few entries that had a "-" as values.  Once they were removed  the data set worked just fine.  So it was not anything with the Excel functions or formulas - those worked just fine.  The dashes as values were creating issues when trying to convert the data set into a time series set in R.  Once again, thanks for all of your help.